# Using filter_var() to verify date?

Tags: php, filtering

I'm obviously not using [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) correctly. I need to check that the user has entered a valid date, in the form "dd/mm/yyyy".

This simply returns whatever I passed as a date, while I expected it to return either the date or 0/null/FALSE in case the input string doesn't look like a date:

```
$myregex = "/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/";
print filter_var("bad 01/02/2012 bad",FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array("options"=>array("regexp"=> $myregex)));
```

If someone else uses this function to check dates, what am I doing wrong? Should I use another function to validate form fields?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the `validateDate()` function at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205 .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$myregex = '~^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$~';
```

The regex matched because you just require that pattern *anywhere* in the string. What you want is *only* that pattern and nothing else. So add `^` and `$`.

Note that this still doesn't mean the value is a *valid date*. `99/99/9999` will pass that test. I'd use:

```
if (!DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $string))
```

Comment: According to my tests, your `createFromFormat()` conditional will not catch a string like `99/99/9999`.  It will catch `baddate` though.

Comment: `createFromFormat()` consider valid the date `2019-02-31`

Comment: @Zauker *sigh* PHP…

Answer (score 27):

Using regex to validate date is a bad idea ..  Imagine `99/99/9999` can easily be seen as a valid date .. you should [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

```
bool checkdate ( int $month , int $day , int $year )
```

Simple Usage

```
$date = "01/02/0000";
$date = date_parse($date); // or date_parse_from_format("d/m/Y", $date);
if (checkdate($date['month'], $date['day'], $date['year'])) {
    // Valid Date
}
```

Comment: **Attention** if you perform `date_parse( '2019-02-313' );` the result has `31` as day value. Maybe in this case you need to check the value of the field `$date['error_count']`

Answer (score 6):

A simple and convenient way to verify the date in PHP is a [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function. 
You can validate the date with only one line:

```
strtotime("bad 01/02/2012 bad"); //false
strtotime("01/02/2012"); //1325455200 unix timestamp
```

Comment: Great for a short fix.  But be careful of MM/DD/YYYY being read backwards to DD/MM/YYYY or other types of traps.

Comment: Did you try also with this value '2019-02-31' ? :) `strtotime` respond with a Unix Timestamp, but maybe you have to consider invalid this date.

Answer (score 5):

Why using a heavy RegEx, while there is a native [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) PHP-class?

```
$value = 'badbadbad';

try {
    $datetime = new \DateTime($value);

    $value = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // Invalid date
}
```

Always returns the format you were expecting, if a valid datetime string was inserted.

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is posted by @baba, but the code posted doesn't work fine in certain conditions.

For example if you try to validate this date "2019-12-313";

```php
$date = date_parse("2019-12-313");
```

the function returns this array:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2019
    [month] => 12
    [day] => 31
    [hour] => 
    [minute] => 
    [second] => 
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 1
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [10] => Unexpected character
        )

    [is_localtime] => 
)
```

so, if you perform the command:

```php
checkdate($date['month'], $date['day'], $date['year']);
```

checkdate will returns a true value because the value of `$date['day']` is 31 instead of 313.

to avoid this case maybe you have to add a check to the value of `$date['error_count']`

the @baba example updated

```php
$date = "2019-12-313";
$date = date_parse($date); // or date_parse_from_format("d/m/Y", $date);
if ($date['error_count'] == 0 && checkdate($date['month'], $date['day'], $date['year'])) {
    // Valid Date
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check date by using this function:

```
function is_date_valid($date, $format = "Y-m-d"){
    $parsed_date = date_parse_from_format($format, $date);
    if(!$parsed_date['error_count'] && !$parsed_date['warning_count']){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

How to use it:

```
$is_valid = is_date_valid("2021-8-1"); // it will return boolean.
```

Note: You can change the format of the date via pass the format in the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the start and end for your regex like this:

```
$myregex = "/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myregex = "~^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$~";

print filter_var("bad 01/02/2012 bad",FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array("options"=>array("regexp"=> $myregex)));
```

Comment: Please consider explaining what your code does to add to the already existing 7 answers in the thread

Comment: That way you have a filter for exact dates from 1900-01-01 to 2099-12-31

Answer (score 0):

A more succinct way of validating date would be to use `DateTime::createFromFormat`

Here's a function that adequately handles it:

```
    function isValidDate(string $date, string $format = 'Y-m-d')
    {
        $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        
        return ($dateObj && $dateObj->format($format) == $date) ? true : false;
    }
```

Check date is valid using:

```
    $dateString = "";
    
    if(isValidDate($dateString, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    {
        //Date is valid
    }
    else
    {
        //Date is not valid
    }
```

Just substitute with desired format(s), and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

You received a lot of answers that indicated the RegEx would allow for an answer of 99/99/9999. That can be solved by adding a little more to the RegEx. If you know you'll never have a date outside of the years 1900-2099... you can use a RegEx like this:

```
/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](0[1-9]|1[012])[/](19|20)\d\d$/
```

That will validate a date of this format: dd/mm/YYYY

Between: 01/01/1900 - 31/12/2099

If you need more years, just add them near the end. |21|22|23|24|25 (would extend it to the year 2599.)