# CI Form Validation of Date. with input type="date"

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, date

validating a form with that has an input type="date" which takes input mm/dd/yyyy
however if i var_dump the results it comes out as yyyy-mm-dd.

## 1 do I validate the input type "mm/dd/yyyy", or do i validate "yyyy-mm-dd".

---im assuming I validate what the var_dump gives me which is yyyy-mm-dd.

## 2 More importantly I am having a hard time finding out the simplest way of going about validating date.

---I am not sure how to go about validating the date without going through by hand and checking every single date. Is there some built in functions that I could use, and how would I go about implementing that in with my CI form validations I already have.

```
function check_registration($post_data)
    {
        // Validations:
        // first_name
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', "trim|required");
        // last_name
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', "trim|required");
        // email
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', "trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]");
        // password
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', "trim|required|min_length[6]");
        // confirm_password
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password', "trim|required|matches[password]");
        // DOB
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOB', 'Date of Birth', "trim|required");

        // run validations:
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === False)
        {
            // set flash data errors
            $this->session->set_flashdata("reg_first_name_error", form_error('first_name'));
            $this->session->set_flashdata("reg_last_name_error", form_error('last_name'));
            $this->session->set_flashdata("reg_email_error", form_error('email'));
            $this->session->set_flashdata("reg_password_error", form_error('password'));
            $this->session->set_flashdata("reg_confirm_password_error", form_error('confirm_password'));
            $this->session->set_flashdata("reg_DOB_error", form_error('DOB'));
            redirect('/');
        }
        // No errors:
        else
        {
            $this->insert($post_data);
            redirect('/success');

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

-Ants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set your own callback rule

   ```
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOB', 'Date of Birth', "trim|required|callback_dob_check");
   ```
2. Write the function inside same controller. Date validation idea taken from: [Using filter_var() to verify date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746332/using-filter-var-to-verify-date).

   ```
   public function dob_check($str){
       if (!DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $str)) { //yes it's YYYY-MM-DD
           $this->form_validation->set_message('dob_check', 'The {field} has not a valid date format');
           return FALSE;
       } else {
           return TRUE;
       }
   }
   ```

More info on DateTime:createFromFormat http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php. I would stick to YYYY-MM-DD format, as it's quite often.