yajra datatables search not working in Laravel
$users = User::leftJoin('nominee_masters', 'nominee_masters.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->leftJoin('branch_masters', 'branch_masters.id', '=', 'users.branch_id')
                ->leftJoin('vw_subscriptions', 'vw_subscriptions.id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->leftJoin('cities as user_city', 'user_city.id', '=', 'users.city')
                ->leftJoin('admins', 'admins.id', '=', 'users.sales_id')
                ->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('admins.e_role', '!=', '5')
                          ->orWhereNull('admins.e_role');
                })
                ->select(
                    'users.id as DT_RowIndex', 
                    'users.member_id', 
                    'users.name', 
                    DB::raw("CASE WHEN users.branch_id = 0 THEN 'Website Customer' ELSE branch_masters.branch_name END AS branch_name"),
                    'users.mobile', 
                    'user_city.city as city', 
                    'users.created_at as join_date', 
                    'admins.name as empname', 
                    'vw_subscriptions.has_subscription'
                )->orderBy('users.id','desc');
    
            return Datatables::of($users)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->editColumn('join_date', function ($user) {
                    return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($user->join_date));
                })
                ->editColumn('empname', function ($user) {
                    return $user->empname ?? 'N/A';
                })
                ->addColumn('action', function ($user) {
                    // Make sure $user is returning valid data and no undefined indexes
                    $btn = '<ul class="table-controls">';
                    $btn .= '<li><a href="/users/edit/'.$user->id.'">Edit</a></li>'; // Example action button
                    $btn .= '</ul>';
                    return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);

This is my controller code, that i am using to list out the records, initially the table displays the data, but when searching anything, it searches makes a search query for just users table.
For example:
branch_name is the column from branch_masters, but when searched the query uses users.branch_name, which results in error.
If anyone could tell what am I doing wrong here

I did not find any search functionality in your code.

You'll have to use manual search to filter using custom column.

I managed to sort the issue with default search, it is working now but the only issue is with date searching, as it does not allow searching for '26-08-2024' format instead it uses '2024-08-26' this format, this is the only issue right now.

for that you will have to check whether the entered text contains valid date or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746332/using-filter-var-to-verify-date then format the date.
